# Using the fact that sin and cos are bounded to show divergence

Tags: calculus

Im trying to check whether the folowing converge or diverge

$$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{ \cos(1/n) }{\sqrt{n}}, \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{ \sin(1/n) }{\sqrt{n}}$$

I claim that they both diverge by comparison test since

$$ \frac{\cos(1/n)}{\sqrt{n}} \geq \frac{-1}{\sqrt{n} } $$

an since $\sum \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$ is divergent we get our result. the same idea for sine one. IS this correct?

Comment: This is obviously incorrect. By your argument, every positive series should diverge since $a_n \ge -1$, so $\sum_n a_n \ge \sum_n -1$. But actually your argument only shows that your sum must be $\ge - \infty$, which is an obvious fact.

Comment: With your argument, you will get that $\sum_{n\ge 1} \frac{\cos(1/n)}{\sqrt{n}} \ge -\infty$...

Comment: hint  :$\exists m >n : cos (\frac{1}{n})>\frac{1}{2}\\\to \Sigma_{m}^{\infty}\frac{cos (\frac{1}{n})}{\sqrt n}>\Sigma_{m}^{\infty}\frac{(\frac{1}{2})}{\sqrt n}\to \infty$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They're series with positive terms.

We have $\cos\dfrac1n>\dfrac12$ for all $n\ge 1$, hence 
$$\frac{\cos\bigl(\frac 1n\bigr)}{\sqrt n}>\frac1{2\sqrt n},$$
which diverges.

As to the other series, $\dfrac{\sin\bigl(\frac 1n\bigr)}{\sqrt n}\sim_\infty\dfrac1{n\sqrt n}$, which converges.

Comment: I think that there is a mistake in your answer, you examine the same series twice.

Comment: Oops! Sorry for the typo (absent minded on copying-pasting!). Thank you for pointing it!

Comment: Oh yes! Don't know what I was thinking of at the time. Actually I'd use equivalents. Thank you for pointing the problem!